# Do object arrays in Java have default values?

Tags: java, arrays

If I construct:

```
Object[][] guy = new Object[5][4];
```

do the spots in my array have default values? Are they null?

Is there a way to assign default values for every spot in the array?

Answer (score 14):

Yes, fields in new arrays are initialized with `null` in Java.

You can use the method [`Arrays.fill()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#fill%28java.lang.Object%5B%5D,%20java.lang.Object%29) to fill all fields in an array with a specific value.

If you have arrays of short length where you statically know what to put it, you can use [array initializers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-10.html#jls-10.6):

```
Object[][] guy = { { obj1, obj2, null, obj3 }, { ... }, ... };
```

You have to type out the full array with all fields (20 in your case) for that, so if you want to put the same value in every place, `fill()` is probably more convenient.

Arrays of primitive types btw. are initialized with the various variants of 0 and with `false` for boolean arrays (as long as you don't use an initializer). The rules for array initialization are the same as for the initialization of fields, and can be found [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.5) in the Java Language Specification.

Comment: It should be mentioned that `Arrays.fill(array, new MyObject())` only creates a *single* object which is then assigned to *all* elements, which might be unintended in many use cases with object arrays.

Answer (score 9):

The existing answers are all correct, but there is one bit to add in your particular example.  Although reference arrays are defaulted to null, multi-dimensional arrays have the first dimension  implictly created.

For example, in your case the first dimension wont be null, but will in fact point to another array:

```
Object[][] guy = new Object[5][4];
System.out.println(guy[0]);
--> Output will be [Ljava.lang.Object;@5e743399
```

Answer (score 1):

[All variables/fields are initialized in Java.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.5)

Consult http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/

Comment: You mean primitives not `Number`s. And `boolean`s are false.

Comment: Non primitives are references, initialized to null.

Answer (score 1):

In Java, objects initializations assume the default value "null".

Answer (score 1):

Primitive types are initialized by default values, Referenced types are NOT initialised (so they are null)

Try to run code snippet to see what happens
public class ArraysSample {

```
/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Object[][] objAr = new Object[4][5];
    for (Object[] objects : objAr) {
        for (Object object : objects) {
            System.out.print(object + "\t");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

    int[][] primitievArray = new int[4][5];
    for (int[] is : primitievArray) {
        for (int i : is) {
            System.out.print(i + "\t");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

}
```

}

---

null    null    null    null    null
null    null    null    null    null
null    null    null    null    null
null    null    null    null    null
0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can have default assigning, for instance :

instead of:

```
char[][] c = new char[5][4];
```

you can:

```
char[][] c = {{'a','b','c','x','B'}, {'A','Z','w','Z','S'},
{'A','Z','w','Z','S'},{'A','Z','w','Z','S'}};
```

Comment: `Char` needs to be `char` here.

Comment: missed that, Thanks @PhilippWendler :P