# The array is only read from, never written to

Tags: java, arrays

Good morning,
I create this class in java :

```
public class MapPoint {          
    public MapPoint() {
      this.tag = new String() ;
      this.Id = 0 ;
    }

public long Id;
public double lon;
public double lat;
public String tag; 

}
```

but when I want to create an array of `MapPoint` in my main function like this :

```
public class mainTestClass {


    public static void main(String[] args){ 
       MapPoint[] mapPoints = new MapPoint[100];
       mapPoints[0].setId(2);
       System.out.println(mapPoints[0].Id);

   }
}
```

I have this hint

> "The array is only read from, never written to"

and when I run my program I have this error :

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException     at
>   mainTestClass.main(mainTestClass.java:34).

please help

thanks.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14920450/do-object-arrays-in-java-have-default-values

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have just declared an array that can contains at most 100 MapPoint objects. Now, you need to create an object in the array.

```
mapPoints[0] = new MapPoint();
mapPoints[0].setId(2);
```

When you're doing `MapPoint[] mapPoints = new MapPoint[10];` it's like in this situation :
[image]

That's why you got a `NullPointerException`.

Answer (score 2):

When you create an array like:

```
MapPoint[] mapPoints = new MapPoint[100];
```

You're not creating an array with 100 mappoints.

You're creating an array that has space to hold 100 reference to map points.

so You need to create a MapPoint yourself, and put it in the array.

Answer (score 1):

Thats because you have to initialize the variable first.

```
mapPoints[0] = new MapPoint().setId(2);
```

Comment: That would work only if `setId` is returning a `MapPoint` object.